# ViewFlipper with only one ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-animation, viewflipper

I need to make a slideshow that switches from different Bitmaps (where the Bitmap came from the image path that I converted it into an image). I want to make this in ViewFlipper with only one ImageView. I really need this please help.

Comment: "I want to make this in ViewFlipper with only one ImageView" -- AFAIK, that's not really possible. The point behind `ViewFlipper` is to flip between multiple views.

Comment: @CommonsWare I watched online videos in Youtube on how to make a slideshow and it uses ViewFlipper. If this is not possible how can I make a slideshow using bitmaps. Please help Im stuck.

Comment: "I watched online videos in Youtube on how to make a slideshow and it uses ViewFlipper" -- yes, but presumably it uses two or more `ImageView` widgets. What makes you think that it is necessary to only use one `ImageView` widget?

Comment: @CommonsWare Because the way I access the images are through database and they are stored as text I just converted it into Bitmap. And I have no clue on how to do this. Please.. I really need help I've never done a serious application on Android before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Imageview dynamically:

```
 viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
 for(int i=0;i<image_array.length;i++)
        {
         ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
         image.setBackgroundResource(res);
         viewFlipper.addView(image);
        }
```

This way you can avoid creating multiple imageviews in xml file.

Another Solution:

Create ViewFlipper with only one ImageView in xml file:

```
        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/vf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_flipper"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </RelativeLayout>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

Considering you have a button which will load the next image,write the below code in its onClick:

```
 int current_image=0;
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_flipper);
 f_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                current_image++;
                imageView.setImageResource(image_array[current_image]);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes I already tried this but the next image is not appearing.

Comment: please check that weather you are getting image correctly from the image path or not

Comment: Yes Im getting all the image path.. but Im trying this one

Comment: make sure that you download the image correctly and set them in the imageview.If you do that correctly then the above solution will definitely work

Comment: By the way why do I need to declare an integer? Im using Bitmap.

Comment: The integer is maintaining the index of the image array.However it is up to you that how you will create the logic of your code.